# High levels of creatinine 20mg/dl and urease 430mg/dl

Tags: dogs

I have a dog GSD, 3.5 years old. His condition is deteriorating day by day. His creatinine level is 20 and urea level is 430 mg/dl.
Report link: http://9url.in/R7B5SL68SA

Can he be saved ? Was there any case where the dog recovered from such levels ? Is it better to give euthanasia ?

Comment: That's *really* young for kidney issues - I'm not a vet, but we did take care of an elderly dog with kidney issues for 3-4 years before he passed on, so any other information on the dog might help